# react google maps render custom html on map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm using `@react-google-maps/api ^2.12.1` in my react project. I want to create an interactive HTML component as a marker on the map. Still, on every documentation of google maps, I only find how to change a marker icon to set as a static icon image or how to set a label text, but not how to add an HTML component to a specific coordinate on the map. Could anyone help me?